# "ls" freezes in the home folder

Tags: home-directory

My system: Lenovo t431s, 12.04.  LAMP stack (it's used for web development), otherwise pretty vanilla.

Applications occasionally freezes when accessing the home folder.

I think I saw advice suggesting a reboot when this happens, but I can't find that page again.

Take with a grain of salt, I don't think it is related to any GUI because it also happens in the terminal.  In the case of being in terminal, if I "ls" in ~/, it stops responding.  It's not happening now, so I can't remember if Ctrl-C restores control.

It's intermittent: usually I have no trouble, but once the home folder becomes unavailable, it doesn't come back.  What I mean by that, even when opening Nautilus, another terminal window, etc., I won't be able to see the files in the home folder until I reboot.

I realized yesterday that this problem also causes trouble with apps. I installed EasyTag and it always locked up.  I figured out that EasyTag locked up because it was trying to read my home folder, and I fixed it by changing the default directory.

Is this a well-known problem (it's an old version) with a well-known solution?  I can't find it.  I could upgrade to 14.04, but without seeing a discussion of the problem, I can't be sure it's fixed there.  I don't want the potential hassle of an upgrade without some reasonable expectation that it fixes the problem.

Comment: If your HDD supports SMART, run some diagnostics with GSmartControl (you can install it through software center). You may have a hardware issue. Also check the file-system integrity with [`fschk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/fsck.8.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My fstab file mounts several shared folders on my home network to folders in my home directory.  When I take my laptop out, the links are broken.

I only noticed the problem when I attempted to use a program that wanted to read my home directory.  Since I don't do that often, the issue felt intermittent.

Remove those lines from the fstab, and to make a script file (and launcher) to mount those folders when I need them.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem is that your filesystem is either corrupted or is not optimal for Linux (like NTFS) which produce that effect. Also a failing disk can produce the same effect. To verify neither of those reasons affect you, you must from a Live Environment run `fsck` on the affected partitions (ie. `sudo fsck /dev/sda1`) and check the SMART values with a SMART tool (ie. `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda`).

Is important that you create a backup of all your important data somewhere safe, preferable that can be unplugged of the system.

Comment: I set up my computer with an ext4 partition for /home on /dev/sda3.

Comment: (The five-minute edit limit expired while I was looking for a flash drive.)


The partition passed smartctl, though I'm not able to interpret the detailed results.  I'm not sure how I should run fsck.  Since the computer is running, fsck warns of certain (inevitable?) dire consequences if I continue.  Would you normally do this with a live-usb?  (I would have tried it already if my kids hadn't stolen all of my flash drives.)

Comment: @chuckj you must do it while the partition is not mounted. If it's mounted fsck will refuse to run.